# Securing External Link

Tags: html

The HTML  tag has an attribute to verify that your external referenced files have not being modified on transit.  What is that attribute?

**What is that attribute?** For HTML  tag has an attribute to verify that your external referenced files have not being modified on transit.

Comment: The integrity attribute allows a browser to check the fetched script to ensure that the code is never loaded if the source has been manipulated. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_integrity.asp

Answer (score 0):

"**integrity**" attribute is used to give permission to the browser to check the fetched script to make ensure the source code is never loaded if an unexpected manipulation has been made. It is used to check that whether the third party has been altered the resource or not.